# Access parameters from path using react found package

Tags: reactjs

I am using ***found*** package for routing my **react.js** app.How can i get search parameters from path?

Comment: Using the pure URLSearchParams may be the way to go? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: thanks for the reply,no other ways with this package?